# postgres/Sequelize: Edit an object in jsonb array if its property's value matches

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a db `home` with a table `room` having a column `appliances` which stores a jsonb array. It has values like

```js
[{
    "name": "TV",
    "uuid": "21"
  },
  {
    "name": "Oven",
    "uuid": "22"
  }
]
```

Now, i want to edit the value with `uuid` `22` and set it to `{"name":"Fridge","uuid":23}`. How can i do it? None on the answers explaining jsonb_set etc. have helped me. It doesn't have to be a sequelize query, i am comfortable with raw query too.

Comment: What is the datatype of your columns `appliances`

Comment: @AkhileshMishra jsonb[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your Data Type is jsonb[] and given data set, the simplest solution of your problem is `array_replace`:

Try this:

```
update room set appliances= array_replace(appliances,'{"name": "Oven","uuid": "22"}', '{"name": "Fridge","uuid": "23"}');
```

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9s9cc8t8AaVBJ3GRtTQsD/0)**

No need of `jsonb_set`. It works with jsonb only.